# Why does cookbook_file resource in this Ruby each loop not actually copy files in Chef recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've been using Ruby/Chef for about 8 hours now :) so hopefully this is something simple.

Why is it that this loop does not work in my Chef recipe? But if I perform these separately it functions as desired (placing cookbook repo files on the server chef recipe is executed on)?

Does not place service files in /etc/systemd/system/

```
["airflow.service", "airflow-webserver.service", "airflow-scheduler.service"].each do |f|        
    cookbook_file '/etc/systemd/system/#{f}' do
        action :create
        source f
    end
end
```

Properly places files /etc/systemd/system/

```
cookbook_file '/etc/systemd/system/airflow.service' do
        action :create
        source 'airflow.service'
end

cookbook_file '/etc/systemd/system/airflow-scheduler.service' do
    action :create
    source 'airflow-scheduler.service'
end

cookbook_file '/etc/systemd/system/airflow-webserver.service' do
    action :create
    source 'airflow-webserver.service'
end
```

Comment: Very easy, when you use `'` the `string` isn't interpolated; you'll need to use `"` instead. Try doing: `cookbook_file "/etc/systemd/system/#{f}" do` and it should work

Comment: "Does not work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @JörgWMittag are you having a bad day? It's Christmas. I've updated my question with some clarity. I've already accepted an answer so some people understood but yes its difficult to search later. It was myself not being familiar with Ruby but it's been cleared up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby, single-quoted strings are read literally, whereas double-quoted strings interpolate "special characters" (with backs-slashes), and inner variables.

For example:

```
[1] pry(main)> world = "earth"
[2] pry(main)> puts 'hello #{world}\ntesting 123'
hello #{world}\ntesting 123
[3] pry(main)> puts "hello #{world}\ntesting 123"
hello earth
testing 123
```

Since you used a single-quoted string, it's being treated as literally `/etc/systemd/system/#{f}`. By using double-quotes, you can interpolate the variable - such as `/etc/systemd/system/airflow-webserver.service`.